# MySql queries from elisp?

Tags: elisp

How can I make SQL queries from within emacs scripts to MySql then print the result set?

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script

(setq sql "select id, name
from foobar
order by name
")

(princ sql)
```

Comment: I like emacs, but to me, I'd start getting concerned if I was writing a sql connector for emacs. :)

Comment: Emacs is simply a Lisp interpreter.  Much of the functionality that you see in Emacs can be traced back to Lisp code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a really reliable way to use mysql I would suggest using python mysql libraries via [pymacs](http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/).

If you need it just working use mysql comand line client? Mysql is quite easy to use in scripts. 
Check out the example below

```
$ mysql -u root -p<password> -B <db> --execute="select * from projects"

p_id    p_timestamp     p_name  p_manager_id    p_status
1       2009-04-14 14:42:00     Test1   3       1
2       2009-04-14 14:42:13     Test2   3       1
```

The output should be easy to interpret as it looks like tab separated CSV. So it should be ok for most scenarios.

Comment: Shell'ing out is inefficient but it will work. 

(split-string (shell-command-to-string "mysql -u root -p<password> -B <db> --execute='select id,name from projects'") )

Answer (score 3):

These may assist you:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlMode

http://atomized.org/2008/10/enhancing-emacs%E2%80%99-sql-mode/

Comment: This simply starts a MySql subprocess in a buffer then keys are bound to send sql statements to the process in the other buffer.  It's almost like working from MySql from a shell.